# Annotate/Highlight Safari webpages, and preserve highlights forever

Tags: safari, software-recommendation, safari-extensions

I am looking for a Safari extension or a built-in tool to highlight or annotate webpages. I want to be able to add notes and shapes that are preserved forever.

I've already tried Liner and Highlight to share, but couldn't find other tools.

Edit:

I found an extension called `Highlighter for Safari`, I bought it and refunded it right away, because it access the following permissions:
[image]

Comment: Could you explain why Liner and Highlight didn't fit your needs?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd trust a Safari Extension to save annotations "forever". My advice would be to press File > Export as PDF, then use an annotator that follows the pdf specification like Apple's Preview or PDF Expert to add annotations.

Comment: the only way to do that is to save the webpage.

Comment: @abc `Liner` didn't work, when I tap it, it shows an empty box. I tried to restart Safari but no luck.

Comment: @jackgmarch I think this is the best way to do it, until now. But it really helps if I just got back to a website after sometime and it loads all my annotation and highlights.

Comment: I found a tool, but didn't work for me. Check the edit, @abc

Comment: Any tool that will annotate a webpage will require the permissions to read all data, so I wouldn't refund it just because of that

Answer (score 1):

Use the Print command

then Select Save as PDF

Now you can use Adobe for Highlights and Notes

[image]